# События Activity при переводе приложения в закладки

Tags: android, activity

Какие события происходят при добавления приложения в закладки (сворачивании) в Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть вполне [исчерпывающая статья](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle) на эту тему. На картинке все довольно понятно расписано, даже при условии слабого английского. onPause когда активити пропадает с глаз, onStop и onDestroy когда экземпляр активити вычищается из памяти. Если активити несколько, они могут "удалятся" не одновременно, не забывайте об этом